# Pandas Pivot table formatting(columns formatting)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Here is the sample dataframe

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'min': [1, 2, 3,4,5], 'max': [1, 2, 3,4,5],'median': [1, 2, 3,4,5],'colors': ['red', 'white', 'blue','black','yellow'],'key': ['A', 'B', 'C','D','F']})
```

[image]

After applying pivot table, the output looks like below.

```
test.pivot(index='key', columns='colors', values=['min','max','median'])
```

[image]

Instead I would like to achieve like below where metrics are grouped under each color as columns.

Is there any way I format the pivot to below, any help would be greatly appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swaplevel then sort index:

```
(test.pivot(index='key', columns='colors', values=['min','max','median'])
     .swaplevel(0,1, axis=1)
     .sort_index(axis=1)
)
```

Another way is to use `set_index` instead of `pivot`, then `stack/unstack` properly:

```
test.set_index(['colors','key']).stack().unstack(level=(0,-1))
```

Output:

```
colors   black            blue             red               white              yellow            
         max median  min  max median  min  max median  min   max median  min    max median  min
key                                                                                            
A        NaN    NaN  NaN  NaN    NaN  NaN  1.0    1.0  1.0   NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN  NaN
B        NaN    NaN  NaN  NaN    NaN  NaN  NaN    NaN  NaN   2.0    2.0  2.0    NaN    NaN  NaN
C        NaN    NaN  NaN  3.0    3.0  3.0  NaN    NaN  NaN   NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN  NaN
D        4.0    4.0  4.0  NaN    NaN  NaN  NaN    NaN  NaN   NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN  NaN
F        NaN    NaN  NaN  NaN    NaN  NaN  NaN    NaN  NaN   NaN    NaN  NaN    5.0    5.0  5.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much